# How to get rounded corners on an Electron app?

Tags: node.js, electron, atom-editor

I am currently trying to get rounded corners on an Electron application I'm making. I have tried nearly every solution available on-line at the moment, but none of them make any difference.

How can I round the corners of my Electron app?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Make a frameless transparent window

```
const myWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    transparent: true, 
    frame: false
})
```

And have something like this in the renderer, or apply the style directly to the body tag

```
<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px; border-radius: 5px">My window content</div>
```

Just make sure to also add a custom window titlebar that has `-webkit-app-region: drag`in order to make the window dragable from this element.

Check out the Electron Docs for further informations ;)
https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/frameless-window.md#transparent-window

Comment: I had done this, for some reason it was not working with adding the radius to the body tag, instead I got it working using the transparent frame and just applying the radius to the title-bar div I was using. No idea why it wasn't working the way it says in their docs.

Comment: I was having some trouble with this and it wasn't working because I had the dev tools opening. *roll eyes*

Comment: div ok body not.

Comment: does not work with linux. check https://stackoverflow.com/a/54780438/3563665

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked that way:

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 1360,
  height: 726,
  minWidth: 1360,
  minHeight: 726,
  frame: false,
  transparent: true,
  backgroundColor: '#00FFFFFF',
})
```