# Transparent Windows on Linux (Electron)

Tags: javascript, html, npm, electron

Using the transparent argument and setting it to true when creating a new BrowserWindow in Electron usually gives the window a transparent background... But on Linux that isn't the case for my knowledge

Now I heard you can set some Command Line Arguments...  But that isn't working... It just displays black or white no matter what...

```
// Should set the commandLine arguments and work...

const {app} = require('electron')

app.commandLine.appendSwitch('enable-transparent-visuals');
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('disable-gpu');
```

Now i have heard this is no problem with electron rather a problem with hardware... But i just needed to make sure therefore creating this question!

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/315/how-to-create-a-transparent-window-with-electron-framework

Comment: I did, and it doesn't work...

Comment: try to set the rgba attribute of body tag the rgba(255,255,255,0.5). Will it work?

Comment: It will help us if can describe your machine and OS.

Comment: Maybe you can also share your source in a repo ?

Comment: This also does not seem to work from the outside, using the `teransset` linux commandline. Something inherent in Chromium I suspect, but my knowledge of Electron architecture is insufficient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have encounter the same problem as you and so I have written :

- this StackOverFlow question :
  [Can't succeed in making transparent window in Electron (javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53538215/cant-succeed-in-making-transparent-window-in-electron-javascript)
- this Electron issue : https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/15947
- and finally request this feature : https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/16809

Till the requested feature is implemented, the solution is simple just add a delay before launching the window.

<strike>You can clone [this git repo](https://gitlab.com/doom-fr/electron-transparency-bug), put the delay to 500, and normally magic will appear.</strike>

EDIT 1 :
Use this repo : https://gitlab.com/doom-fr/electron-transparency-demo

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/doom-fr/electron-transparency-demo
cd electron-transparency-demo
npm install
npm start
# or npm run startWithTransparentOption
# or npm run startWithAllOptions
```

For me, it works out of the box with Debian Jessie and electron 4.0.5, for `npm start`, `npm run startWithTransparentOption` but not with `npm run startWithAllOptions`.

NB : be carefull to set at least 500ms to have chance it works. After you can reduce the delay but it is not stable. It is why an event on transparentReady is needed.

Doom

Comment: @OneGuy I have updated the repo, try. If does not work try the `npm run` command

Comment: Ok cool. For stats, can you tell us your OS, and if it works also with `npm run startWithTransparentOption` and `npm run startWithAllOptions`

Comment: And if you can abound this feature request : https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/16809, it will be cool also. Doom.

Comment: Using Xubuntu currently but on my Home pc i got a few distros installed and they weren’t working either... The distros being Ubuntu, Manjaro, Arch and Kubuntu non seem to be working before this fix and i haven’t got to test this yet... I got more distros but they were the ones i tested this on.... And for the npm run commands, im just getting a missing script error not sure why...

Comment: caution: the delay can be hardware-dependent -- fast CPU, not much delay needed, etc

Answer (score 5):

There do seem to be multiple issues with transparency, on different distributions with differing hardware. There are various suggested workarounds. You might not be able to make transparency work acceptably for your scenario on *all* hardware and distributions.

Examples

- https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2170
- https://github.com/zeit/hyper/pull/842
- https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/15947
- [Can't succeed in making transparent window in Electron (javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53538215/cant-succeed-in-making-transparent-window-in-electron-javascript)

From the Electron docs:

> On Linux, users have to put --enable-transparent-visuals --disable-gpu in the command line to disable GPU and allow ARGB to make transparent window, this is caused by an upstream bug that alpha channel doesn't work on some NVidia drivers on Linux.

https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/frameless-window.md

Comment: Question, about the command line i already added it with:

app.commandLine.appendSwitch('enable-transparent-visuals');
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('disable-gpu');

Comment: Hi, I think I was addressing this part of your question: "But i just needed to make sure therefore creating this question!" basically, there do seem to be multiple issues, and it could be particular to your distribution/hardware. There are some interesting workarounds mentioned in the links - e.g. to delay making the window visible for a few seconds after it is "ready".

Comment: Just to clear it up so far nothing has worked and im assuming nothing will work... Although im up for anybody having an idea on how to fix my problem and try said fix

Comment: Maybe try the delay suggestion from doom in his answer, also it might add value to mention your video card and Linux distro details somewhere.

Comment: Sorry! Upstream bugs in Chrome = one of the least fun parts of working with Electron, but if you log an issue in the right place, it may get sorted.

Comment: Where would you recommend I go and report this?

Comment: I would start with Electron themselves here: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues or consider adding to Doom's issue here if you have the same distribution: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/15947.

Comment: @GrahamMc the upstream bug in Chromium has been fixed 2 years ago (if you are talking about this one https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=369209)

Answer (score 1):

This worked to me:

```
if(process.platform === "linux") {
  app.commandLine.appendSwitch('enable-transparent-visuals');
  app.disableHardwareAcceleration();

  app.on('ready', () => setTimeout(createWindow, 400));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code might work for you. I add explain in comment.

```js
//electron can't be transparent on linux
//see issue on github: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2170

// app.disableHardwareAcceleration(); //use this
//or use these two lines code
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('enable-transparent-visuals');
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('disable-gpu');

//createWindow need to wait(more than about 100ms) if you want the window to be transparent
// app.whenReady().then(createWindow); //this won't work
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('enable-transparent-visuals');
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('disable-gpu');
app.on('ready', () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        createWindow();
    }, 200);
});
```