# Electron transparent window on raspberry pi (4)

Tags: raspberry-pi, electron, raspberry-pi4

As demoed here [Can't succeed in making transparent window in Electron (javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53538215/cant-succeed-in-making-transparent-window-in-electron-javascript), I manage to run the hello world application on a debian buster with background transparency.

However, when I try this demo on a raspberry pi 4 (raspbian desktop), it doesn't work out of the box. I read here https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/315/how-to-create-a-transparent-window-with-electron-framework that it could be caused by some driver bugs.

Can someone help me understand the issue with more depth ?

The need in my project is to display an HD video in the background and a few buttons in the foreground. Chromium-browser does not benefit as much from the hardware acceleration as omxplayer does (and drops frames), so I'm trying not to embed the video in the browser. Instead, I plan to have the smooth omxplayer run in the background and display an electron app with transparency.

Comment: Have you made any progress with this? I'm reading about several driver issues and their compatibility with Chromium versions that may have something to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

(Pi 4B)

Doing some looking into openbox, the docs [here](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:FAQ#How_do_I_get_true_32-bit_transparent_windows.3F) say that you can use:

```
xcompmgr -c -t-5 -l-5 -r4.2 -o.55 &
```

I tested it, and it works with the parameters specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54784577/12793008). You can set the xcompmgr command to run in an autostart file when X initializes.

EDIT: In my testing, the latest electron build where transparency works correctly is `electron@9.2.1`.