# Make radius corners on electron application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I have an electron application and i want to make the window corner's radius.
I try to add `border-radius` on the body but is not working how can i fix that?

Comment: can you put some of your code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get rounded corners on an Electron app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51262645/how-to-get-rounded-corners-on-an-electron-app)